# In Go, how can I automatically coerce my loop index into an uint?

Tags: go

I have a few functions taking an `uint` as their input :

```
func foo(arg uint) {...}
func bar(arg uint) {...}
func baz(arg uint) {...}
```

I have a loop whose limits are both constant `uint` values

```
const (
    Low = 10
    High = 20
)
```

In the following loop, how can I say I want `i` to be a `uint` ? The compiler complains about it being an `int`.

```
for i := Low; i <= High; i++ {
    foo(i)
    bar(i)
    baz(i)
}
```

I don't really want to call `uint(i)` on each function call, and doing the following is correct but makes me feel dirty :

```
var i uint

for i = Low; i <= High; i++ {
    foo(i)
    bar(i)
    baz(i)
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for i := uint(Low); i < High; i++ {
    ...
}
```

also note that `uint()` is not a function call and, when applied to constants and (I believe) signed integers of the same size, happens entirely at compile-time.

Alternatively, though I'd stick with the above, you can type your constants.

```
const (
    Low = uint(10)
    High = uint(20)
)
```

then `i := Low` will also be a `uint`. I'd stick with untyped constants in most cases.

Comment: No cost is not exactly right; converting betwheen primitive types typically has a cost of one instruction, although in some cases there is no cost at all.

Comment: @FUZxxl Thanks for catching that. I've edited the answer to be more accurate; the key point I was trying to make is you don't "call" uint, as the asker seems to think based on the statement "I don't really want to call uint(i)..."

Comment: Yeah, that is true. Also, the cost of a cast is almost nothing.

Comment: @FUZxxl and which instruction might that be? At the time you convert the type to another one, you're telling the compiler to treat it as this type, which then generates different code for it (maybe). The CPU does not do type conversion. [`println(i)` and `println(uint(i))`](http://play.golang.org/p/FsMU-Phpc8) have the [same amount of instructions](http://pastie.org/7443624#14-18,20-24).

Comment: @nemo In case of a conversion between int and uint there is really no cost, as an int usually has the size of one word on the machine the code is compiling on.

Comment: @FUZxxl so in which case there is a cost? I think the statement that a conversion has a cost is wrong. The compiler might generate code that is longer, for example when converting a 32 bit integer to a 64 bit (zero the upper half), but this is in fact a side-effect of the conversion, not the conversion itself. Conversions are dealt with by the compiler.

Comment: @nemo The fact that the code is longer (and therefor there are more instructions to run for the processor) is a cost. As I wrote above: *converting betwheen primitive types typically has a cost of one instruction, although in some cases there is no cost at all.* I don't see how that statement is wrong.

Comment: @FUZxxl Because the conversion is done by the compiler. It has no costs. But the side-effects of the conversion may introduce more or less instructions. But maybe I'm just nitpicking here.

Answer (score 8):

```
for i := uint(Low); i <= High; i++ { //EDIT: cf. larsmans' comment
        foo(i)
        bar(i)
        baz(i)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/KTpy_cS_2l)

Or define the constants to be typed:

```
const (
        Low  uint = 10
        High uint = 20
)

...

for i := Low; i <= High; i++ {
        foo(i)
        bar(i)
        baz(i)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/EKYPvIJZGe)

Comment: No need for `uint(High)` in the first snippet.